# What is the meaning of すこ in ほんとすこ?

Tags: internet-slang

Seen on the internet. Looking around I see others guessing it might be a different form of 本当っすか for 本当ですか, or maybe すこ for すき. Can anyone confirm? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

すこ is a recent slang word that means すき. ほんとすこ is "I really love it".

For some reason, young net users keep coining strange words by changing a single character. Another well-known example is [ぬこ, which just means ねこ](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%AC%E3%81%93).

Comment: Thanks. So there's no supporting reference yet like for ぬこ? ; - )

Comment: Is there any evidence of "young"?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the reference part, you can look [here](https://kimu3.net/20170216/6593).

Basically, like a lot of these internet slang, it was born from a single typo, in this case すこ instead of the intended すき. As people made fun of it as a meme, it eventually became a part of the slang. Note that this type of internet slang in known as なんJ語, being born from the なんでも実況J board on 2ch.